Comparison theorems for ode
Suppose that the functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous in the $\mathbb{R}^2$,
and denote by $y_0(x), z_0(x)$ any solution of the initial value problems
$$
y'(x) =f(x,y),y(x_0)  = y_0 \\
z'(x) = g(x,y),z(x_0)=y_0
$$
respectively. if $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ and $f,g$ are locally Lipshitz,  how to prove in interval $[x_0,b)$,we have $y(x) \leq z(x)$?

$w(x)=z(x)-y(x)$, $w'(x)=g(x,y)-f(x,y)\ge 0$, with $w(x_0)=0$.

This is in the "qualitative analysis" chapter of Teschl - Ordinary Differential Equations and dynamical systems

Do you mean $z'(x)=g(x,y)$ or $z'(x)=g(x,z)$?
